# Convert article to PDF?

Tags: php, form

I was wondering if anyone knows of any way to take the HTML content of a custom module which is placed inside an article and convert the HTML to PDF via the click of a button or so.

So basically the user will have a button "convert to PDF", and the PDF file will be generated with the HTML content, and they will have the option of downloading it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Phoca PDF.  It's a decent extension. https://www.phoca.cz/phocapdf

Comment: I have tried that one, but it was not working. I have a custom template so it may have performed and override on some content files. However, I've used jsPDF and jspdf-AutoTable to sort the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to use [Aspose.PDF Cloud SDK for PHP](https://products.aspose.cloud/pdf/php) to create PDF from HTML.
Here is a quick [example](https://docs.aspose.cloud/display/pdfcloud/Create+PDF+from+HTML):

```
<?php
use Aspose\PDF\PdfApi;
use Aspose\PDF\AsposeApp;

// Initialize API
public $pdfApi = new PdfApi();

// Upload file to Aspose Cloud Storage
$fileName = "output.pdf";
$templateFile = "input.html";
Utils::uploadFile($templateFile);

// Convert file to HTML format
$result = $this->pdfApi->PutCreateDocument($fileName, $templateFile, $dataFile = null, $templateType = "html", $storage = "", $folder = "");
?>
```

**Note**: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.